# what is the purpose of caching (tmp\_WL_user, AdminServer/tmp)?

Tags: caching, weblogic12c

we have an old jar loaded instead of the correct jar. this was a temperory issue and when we restarted the server it picked the correct jar, so I was searching for what might be the cause of this, and I found that there are two places tmp/_WL_user and /AdminServer/tmp they contain copies of application jars. can someone explain the purpose of these two locations and when WebLogic loads the jars from them?

Answer (score 1):

These are temporary application directories. Normally, these files and directories are deleted automatically when no longer needed. However, it is possible to delete them manually to save disk space. Please bear in mind that WLS should be STOPPED prior to deleting these files.

Answer (score 1):

The /tmp/WL_user is actually the cache of your Admin/managed server. In case you accidentally delete the actual jar/war/ear file, your application will still run even if you do a restart of the server. It will only look for the actual location of the jar file only when you remove the /tmp/WL_user directory and restart the servers.

Wroth noting if you have staging enabled, you will also find a directory named 'stage'. This is generally enabled in production where you will find another copy of the jar file. I a not sure of the purpose, but this is again to keep another copy of the jar file to avoid any accidental removal from the original source directory.

Hope this clarifies.